# Difficulty comparing differences in DateTimes

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, comparison

I have a DateTime variable called "lastActivated", that is set to DateTime.Now when the Form_Activated event fires. The goal is to make sure something doesn't happen within the first 1 second of a user clicking the screen from another screen.

```
    DateTime? lastActivate = null; //used to determine the last time the screen was focused. 
    private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lastActivate = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

The code for determining whether it has been longer than 1 second looks like

```
    TimeSpan oneSec = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);

    if (lastActivate == null || (TimeSpan)(lastActivate - DateTime.Now) > oneSec)
    {
        //stuff
    }
```

The above if statement always, ALWAYS fails. Even when the values are:

```
    lastActivate    {11/30/2013 10:23:21 AM}    System.DateTime?
    now {11/30/2013 10:32:48 AM}    System.DateTime
```

(I made a temp value DateTime now = DateTime.Now so I could paste the value here, since I couldn't directly access DateTime.Now's value)

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong, and what I should change to get it to accomplish the goal I am after?

Thanks!

Comment: Side thing. But a timespan has .TotalSeconds which returns total amount of seconds. So you don't need to compare with a 'oneSec' Timespan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last active date is less than current time, you should subtract it from current time:

```
if (!lastActivate.HasValue || (DateTime.Now - lastActivate.Value).TotalSeconds > 1)
{
    //stuff
}
```

Comment: Outstanding! Thank you everyone for your answers. Lazyberezovsky got there first so he gets answer, but all of you were very helpful! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can test the time between two dates by doing this:

```
var lastActivated = DateTime.Now;

if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastActivated).TotalSeconds > 1)
{
    // Do whatever you need.
}
```

[DateTime.Subtract(DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a TimeSpan of the time difference between the two given dates.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem :** You are subtracting in reverse order, you should `subtract` the `lastActivate` Time from the current Time(`DateTime.Now`).
otherwise you will always get `-ve` value when you subtract `DateTime.Now` from `lastActivate` as  `lastActivate` time is always less than the Current Time `(DateTime.Now)`.

**Solution :**

This:

```
(TimeSpan)(lastActivate - DateTime.Now)
```

Should be :

```
(TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - lastActivate)
```

**Complete Code:**

```
TimeSpan oneSec = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);

    if (lastActivate == null || (TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - lastActivate) > oneSec)
    {
        //stuff
    }
```